# What, if anything, is the name FRIDAY an acronym for?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, names, avengers-age-of-ultron

At the end of *Age of Ultron*,

> Tony Stark activates an AI named **FRIDAY** for the final battle in Sovokia against Ultron, as a replacement for JARVIS.

JARVIS is an acronym for for *Just A Rather Very Intelligent System*. What is FRIDAY an acronym for?

Comment: Girl Friday, perhaps?

Comment: Are you asking specifically what the acronym stands for, or what "Friday" may be a reference to (which "Girl Friday" is a theory I've seen batted about in a number of places)?

Comment: Good question. Considering it's written as an acronym on the chip. I just figured we'd find out next Iron Man.

Comment: @phantom42, I'm asking what the acronym stands for

Comment: so, I apparently missed it, but where do we find out that JARVIS is an acronym? It's clearly a reference to Jarvis the butler...

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield It's from the novelization of IM1.

Comment: A [Reddit commenter](http://www.reddit.com/r/Marvel/comments/34tauo/spoiler_aou_acronym_question/cqy1um1) has a fairly decent guess: *“Female-Rendered-Intelligent-Display-And-?”*.

Comment: ... "Yeti". I'm pretty sure the last word is "yeti".

Comment: Freaking Ridiculously Intelligent Data Analysis Yank

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield: That's unintentionally hilarious for anyone familiar with the Defense Grid series of tower defense games... :P

Comment: FYI: I don't think the mere name of something that appears in the movie is a spoiler, so I've tried to make the question more meaningful; if others disagree feel free to roll back.

Comment: **F**reaky **R**obot’s **I**ncapable of **D**estroying the **A**vengers, **Y**et.

Comment: I'm not allowed to post answers to this thread.

"F.R.I.D.A.Y. also known as Female Replacement Intelligent Digital Assistant Youth "

https://ironman.fandom.com/wiki/F.R.I.D.A.Y.

Answer (score 26):

I don’t think it stands for anything (yet). Here’s a picture of the disk; note that it doesn’t contain any periods:

[image: Close-up of a slightly more than thumb-sized black plastic device behing held between thumb and forefinger. The device has a blue panel covering most of the surface with glowy Tron lines on it, and a hand-scrawled label "FRIDAY"]

There’s a minor character in the comics called “Friday” ([Marvel Wiki](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Friday_Stark_(Earth-616))), an AI that Tony develops as his “Girl Friday” AI to be his new assistant. He developed her rather than having to hire another human secretary. I think that’s what this disk is referring to.

Notice the disk labelled Jocasta? That’s the name of another AI from the comics ([Marvel Wiki](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Jocasta_Pym_(Earth-616))) built by Ultron so that he could have a mate, but just as Ultron’s comic origins were changed for the movie, so apparently were Jocasta’s.

Neither of these characters have names that correspond to acronyms in the comics. If they do stand for something, I don’t think it’s been revealed in the canon.

---

**Edit:** I went to see the film, and as Matthew Read correctly points out in comments, as he’s loading it on the screen, it definitely says “F.R.I.D.A.Y.”. I looked quite carefully for an expansion on screen, but I didn’t see anything. Sadface.

I did see that it’s labelled “Mark XLV (45) OS”. He’s using a Mark 43 when the film starts, so I don’t know what happened to the Mark 44. And that doesn’t tell us what FRIDAY stands for.

Comment: To be fair, JARVIS is both an acronym and a reference to the comics character.

Comment: the big question is, what's that third one at the bottom?

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield I’ve seen suggestions that it says *Tadashi* (as in the *Big Hero 6* character), but I haven’t found a screencap to confirm.

Comment: Big hero 6 being another marvel comic and Disney property

Comment: It may be worth noting that "Girl Friday" is almost certainly a reference to Robinson Crusoe's manservant, Man Friday.

Comment: Looks like ...DASY to me.   All the other latter are full height capitals.   I don't see how you get ...DASHI out of that screencap.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield also wondering the same [What were the other A.I. chips and whom are they referring to?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/33907/what-were-the-other-a-i-chips-and-whom-are-they-referring-to)

Comment: In the movie, I recall IM's HUD showing `F.R.I.D.A.Y.`

Comment: @MatthewRead You could be right. I’ll have a look to see if the HUD says anything more about the acronym when I rewatch the film.

Comment: For what it's worth, the character is credited on IMDb, played by Kerry Condon, as [F.R.I.D.A.Y.](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0508207/)  Also, HOLY CRAP THAT'S OCTAVIA FROM ROME.

Comment: [`Tadashi is here.`](http://40.media.tumblr.com/65eec80028c169504b5ca7f7da20629a/tumblr_inline_nnnvssBPi41qdqnkl_500.png)

Comment: What ever acronym invented here for  F.R.I.D.A.Y., Friday is the native man who helps the marooned Robinson Crusoe, becoming his trusted companion in Crusoe's ongoing survival situation. So named because he was first seen on that day of the week. And so a Girl Friday is the female counterpart.

Comment: https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/marvelmovies/images/4/42/F.R.I.D.A.Y_INTERFACE.JPG/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/640?cb=20150821060251

Answer (score 15):

#### It isn't an acronym, such as we know it. It is a nod to a comic artificial intelligence, [Friday](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Friday_Stark_(Earth-616)), Stark designed and used as a digital secretary.

[image: Stark, in a black suit, sits in a chair facing a hologram of FRIDAY floating in front of him. FRIDAY appears as a blonde woman with a ponytail and glasses wearing a pink jacket and skirt and pink shoes. She is seated on the top half of a stool, with a typewriter floating in front of her. Stark gives her a set of orders to which she replies "Yes, Sir!"]

> Tony Stark decided there was no point in trying to hire a new secretary. Instead, he created his own “girl Friday” with a new A.I. program that would appear as a hologram of a young woman. Friday had a sweet, almost child-like disposition and was happy to show up whenever her boss needed her.

Friday grew up over time and Stark's interaction with her had become less frequent. She ultimately became a sort of adoptive daughter over time.

[image: FRIDAY is a green hologram wearing a tank top and jeans, projected over a scarred concrete floor with equipment in the background. The narration text reads "FRIDAY was a holographic secretary and virtual assistant I created way back but I haven't used her in years." Stark: "FRIDAY..." FRIDAY: "You don't have to thrash my emitters, dude. Now I'm all flickery."]

Stark has used other digital assistants in the past, all of them with acronyms for names. Friday is the only known exception.

- H.O.M.E.R. (“Heuristically Operative Matrix Emulation Rostrum”):
- P.L.A.T.O. (“Piezo-Electrical Logistic Analytical Tactical Operator”):
- V.I.R.G.I.L. (“Virtual Integrated Rapidly-evolving Grid-based Intelligent Lifeform”) - from an alternative timeline
- [JOCASTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jocasta_%28comics%29): Jocasta was, first, a person then became an enslaved artificial intelligence which helped Stark before regaining her body later.

Comment: What's that quote from?

Comment: Not a bad answer, except on-screen (as noted by alex in his edit), it definitely says F.R.I.D.A.Y. indicating it is an acronym in the MCU.

Comment: Indicating lazy writers who wanted to tease viewers with an acronym for something that appeared in a comic book and calling it an Easter Egg. Acronym, not an acronym, not a big deal in the slightest. Someone could just as easily make one up and not have it confirmed one way or the other. I was not trying to make up an acronym, I was trying to explain the comic-related ORIGIN of it.

Comment: Note that the other chip which is fully visible in alexwlchan's still from the movie shows a blurry, but readable, JOCASTA.

Comment: JOCASTA doesn't seem to be an acronym, as far as I can tell...IIRC it was the name of a villain-created android whose mind, but not body, switched sides.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really an acronym for anything that I'm aware of. It just stands for, or represents the shortened version of the saying: My girl Friday, or gal Friday. It's a saying that represents an efficient and faithful female assistant. For example, "I'll have my girl Friday get the papers together." Although usually the saying is most commonly applied to a female, it can also represent a devoted male servant or assistant.

Comment: Welcome to SFFSE!  Do you have any evidence to back it up?  As it stands, this answer doesn't really add anything to the answers already posted.

Comment: No, not really. It's just that Tony Stark addresses the AI in Avengers 2 as "My girl Friday." It could be an acronym for something, but as it stands I think it's just supposed to be a pun or play on the saying. I could be wrong.

Comment: "Man Friday" is the original - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friday_(Robinson_Crusoe)